# how to take disk snapshot for every 10 minuites using cloud function or gcloud commands or something?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The default disk snapshot schedule can only take snapshots every approximately one hour
but i want to take disk snapshots for every 10 minuites automatically.

I want to take disk snapshots for every 10 minuites automatically using cloud function or gcloud commands or something

Comment: Does it not strange to perform a backup every 10 minutes? What's your type of use case that requires this?

Comment: I do not recommend using snapshots for live running systems. You can easily save snapshots that are corrupted. Use a different backup technology such as traditional file backups and snapshots taken while the VM instance is shutdown.

Comment: I'm targeting an RTO of 5 minutes, but I've heard that GCP's default disk snapshot schedule is once every hour. Also, a maximum of 6 snapshots can be created for each disk, so I asked about a method to create snapshots every 10 minutes. I'm currently applying this using Google's provided APIs, specifically DisksClient and SnapshotsClient. Thank you

Comment: You might be able to create and restore a small VM in 5 minutes (RTO), but I still would not use Google snapshots for my RPO. Make sure you really understand how snapshots work and why they are not a good idea when taken from live machines. There will be corruption. The unknown is how much corruption and that depends on what is running on the system, what data is stored in memory, etc. Also important is selecting the right file system type.